# jquery - change background image on current clicked element

Tags: jquery

I have multiple thumbsup and thumbsdown elements for specific movies in which users can thumbsup and thumbsdown. I need to change the background image of a class when clicked, but only for that particular `<a>` element. I can't seem to properly use the `.this` option to target that specific record so it only changes the background image for that specific element when clicked.

Right now this code changes the image for all the elements when clicked. For instance, if I click the `thumbsup` then it changes the background image for all three of them regardless of the `id`

My HTML

```
<a class="thumbsup" id="1"></a>
<a class="thumbsdown" id="1"></a>
<a class="thumbsup" id="2"></a>
<a class="thumbsdown" id="2"></a>
<a class="thumbsup" id="3"></a>
<a class="thumbsdown" id="3"></a>
```

My jquery Code

```
$( ".thumbsup" ).live("click", function(){
    movie_id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/voting.php?",
        data: "movie_id="+ movie_id+
        "&thumbsup=1",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.thumbsup').css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_up_hover.png)");
            $('.thumbsdown').css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_down.png)");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$( ".thumbsdown" ).live("click", function(){
    movie_id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/voting.php?",
        data: "movie_id="+ movie_id+
        "&thumbsdown=1",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.thumbsdown').css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_down_hover.png)");
            $('.thumbsup').css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_up.png)");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `<a>` doesnt fit in this usecase. Its not semantic. Use `<button>` instead.

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting?

Comment: Im not getting an error, the image background simply does not change

Comment: Recheck if the image paths are actually correct.

Comment: they are, I already checked that. The code currently changes the images for all the elements regardless of the `id`

Comment: use use ID's multiple times, that is not valid. ID's have to be **unique**. If you use a DTD other than HTML5 pure numeric-id's are invalid html too. [W3C-ID specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: they are used multiple times, but the jquery only selects the specific class which contains only one id, so it should work fine.

Comment: @CesarBielich using same ID multiple time is bad HTML.

Comment: Please reproduce your problem in jsFiddle or jsBin so we can take a look.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/7go72kpw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ID multiple times is invalid HTML, I suggest using a data attribute since you need the id in your ajax call, hence six different IDs are probably not fitting:

```
<button class="thumbsup" data-id="1"></button>
<button class="thumbsdown" data-id="1"></button>
<button class="thumbsup" data-id="2"></button>
<button class="thumbsdown" data-id="2"></button>
<button class="thumbsup" data-id="3"></button>
<button class="thumbsdown" data-id="3"></button>
```

you can then get the id in your function

```
movie_id = $(this).data('id');
```

and update both buttons afterwards using the data-id attribute again

```
$('.thumbsup[data-id=' + movie_id + ']').css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_up_hover.png)");
$('.thumbsdown[data-id=' + movie_id + ']').css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_down.png)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `unique ID` for all element:

```
$( ".thumbsup" ).live("click", function(){
    movie_id = this.id;//you can use this id to change image of specific element
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/voting.php?",
        data: "movie_id="+ movie_id+
        "&thumbsup=1",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#'+movie_id).css("background-image", "url(/images/thumbs_up_hover.png)");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ok this almost works, problem is I need to be able to change the `.thumbsdown` class as well just in case the user had thumbs down it at some point. So if the users clicks thumbsup it replaces it with the hover image and changes the thumbsdown with the standard image. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: If i am understanding well you can replace class and add new one in `success` like `$('#'+movie_id).replaceClass('thumbsup`).addClass('thumbsup`)`